# Find rows that are in between two column dates pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with a two columns CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE and CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE. I want to return all the rows that have a CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE date after 7/1/16 and CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE before 7/31/16. I tried to do this by parsing the 7/1/16 and 7/31/16 strings using python datetime but kept getting a type mismatch so I added two columns in the spreadsheet with those strings copied over and over. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Margaret/Desktop/CP1.csv')

start_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'])
end_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE'])
before_date = pd.to_datetime(df['BEFORE_DATE'])
after_date = pd.to_datetime(df['AFTER_DATE'])

#print(start_dates.sort_values())
#print(df.sort_values(by=['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE']))

x = df[(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'] > df['BEFORE_DATE'][1]) & (df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE'] > df['AFTER_DATE'][1])]
```

Comment: Something seems amiss here. Does your CSV have headers? I would expect `start_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'])` to look something like `df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'])`. Where are `BEFORE_DATE` and `AFTER_DATE` columns coming from if your initial CSV has 2 columns?

Comment: df = df[(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'] > '7-1-16')
       & (df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE'] < '7-31-16')]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE'])
df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE'])
df=df.loc[(df['CURRENT_PLAN_START_DATE']>pd.to_datetime('2016-07-01'))&(df['CURRENT_PLAN_END_DATE']<pd.to_datetime('2016-07-31')),:]
```